# super use for referring to base class method

Tags: python

I am unable to use `super` in Python 2.7.9; is it possible to use it? Code I have been trying:

```
class Base():
   def __init__(self):
      print "It's a Base"
class Secondary(Base):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Secondary,self).__init__()
Secondary()
```

Error:

```
Must be type not classobj
```

Comment: Your `Base()` should be `Base(object)`.

Comment: Please help me understand why Base(object) and not empty braces.

Comment: @Newbee the latter creates an *"old-style"* classes, the former a *"new-style"* class - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/3001761. Note also that this *is* covered in the duplicate - have you read it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer .I've got the solution and also the explanation.